# Sharing model that connects to Database

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder

Im trying to share a model I built to other users in the same company. I've connected the model to datasets thats in a database which I have a connection to. When I share it, the model don't find the data because the other user have a different name on the same connection. How do I set a fixed link to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Without actually giving us an example of your file paths and what your database is I'm assuming you have associated a drive letter to the network location which is different of other PC's?

You could try accessing your data source location using a [UNC path](https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons why this could be going wrong:

- The path to the SDE file doesn't exist in the same location when they open the model
- The credentials you've used can't be shared to your colleagues and they're failing to update proper credentials into the connection file

There are multiple ways to solve this problem:

- Use the Create ArcSDE Connection file at the start of the model. This forces your colleagues to make a new connection file and should guarantee it'll work everytime
- Simply include the .SDE file with the model (ie. 2 files). Making sure to set relative paths inside the model. This can be problematic as you have 2 files now to move and you need to ensure people dont break the expected paths within the model
- Reference the .SDE file on a shared network drive that everyone has access too
- Create a Geoprocessing Package from your successfully run result. Share the GPK with your colleagues. A GPK will include all the components necessary for the model to run. When you create the GPK, you can specify to *reference* the database layers, instead of packaging them up inside

Secondary considerations on SDE file credentials:

- If you databases are setup to use Windows Authentication you can simply pass around connection files and its up to the user/DB to make sure they can connect
- If using DB authentication you may or may not want to save the password within the .SDE file. If you dont save the password, users will need to enter the password when they attempt to run the model